# Flutter: White background Scaffold taking 4.4 ms to render in profile mode

Tags: flutter, performance

I am facing a performance issue in my Flutter app, when running it in profile mode. After some profiling, I observed that the rendering of the background screen, which consists of nothing more than a white-backgrounded Scaffold, takes an unexpectedly long time, specifically 4.4 ms.

[image: Here you can serr]

Could anyone provide why this is happening and how can i prevent this.

Here is the code:

```html
class FinSalaryTrackerEntry extends StatelessWidget {
  const FinSalaryTrackerEntry({super.key});

  static GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Map<String, dynamic> trackerRawModel = {};
    ValueNotifier<ExpenseCategory> selectedCategory = ValueNotifier(ExpenseCategory.values[1]);
    ValueNotifier<DateTime> currentDateTime = ValueNotifier(DateTime.now());
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: FinTheme.defaultWhite,
        leading: IconButton(
            splashColor: Colors.transparent,
            icon: Icon(
              FontAwesomeIcons.chevronLeft,
              color: FinTheme.secondaryTextColor,
            ),
            onPressed: () => FinNavigator.pop(context: context)),
        title: const Text("Expense Details"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: SizeConstraints.defaultPadding),
        child: Form(
          key: formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: SizeConstraints.sidePadding * 4),
                child: FinMoneyInputField(
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      trackerRawModel["money"] = value ?? 0;
                    },
                    moneySymbol: MoneySymbolUtils.getCurrentCountryCurrencySymbol(context: context)),
              ),
              FinChipField(
                validator: (value) {
                  return true;
                },
                onSaved: (value) {
                  trackerRawModel["description"] = value != null && value.isNotEmpty ? value : "- - -";
                },
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: SizeConstraints.defaultPadding * 4),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        const Expanded(
                            child: FinDivider(
                          indentValue: 0,
                        )),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: SizeConstraints.sidePadding),
                          child: Text(
                            "Other Details",
                            style: TextStyle(color: FinTheme.disableColor),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Expanded(
                            child: FinDivider(
                          indentValue: 0,
                        ))
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: SizeConstraints.sidePadding),
                    child: FinSplitContainer(children: [
                      InkWell(
                        splashColor: FinTheme.secondaryColor,
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(SizeConstraints.borderRadius), topLeft: Radius.circular(SizeConstraints.borderRadius)),
                        onTap: () => _openDateTimeDialogue(context: context, currentDateTime: currentDateTime),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: SizeConstraints.sidePadding * 1.2, horizontal: SizeConstraints.sidePadding),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                  child: Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: SizeConstraints.sidePadding / 2),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Date: ",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: responsiveText(context: context, fontSize: 18)),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  ValueListenableBuilder<DateTime>(
                                      valueListenable: currentDateTime,
                                      builder: (context, value, _) {
                                        return Text(
                                          DateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:aa").format(value),
                                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: FinTheme.secondaryTextColor, fontSize: responsiveText(context: context, fontSize: 18)),
                                        );
                                      }),
                                ],
                              )),
                              Icon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.chevronRight,
                                size: responsiveText(context: context, fontSize: 16),
                                color: FinTheme.secondaryTextColor,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        splashColor: FinTheme.secondaryColor,
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(SizeConstraints.borderRadius), bottomRight: Radius.circular(SizeConstraints.borderRadius)),
                        onTap: () => _openCategoryBottomSheetModel(selectedCategory: selectedCategory, context: context),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: SizeConstraints.sidePadding * 1.2, horizontal: SizeConstraints.sidePadding),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                  child: Row(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: SizeConstraints.sidePadding / 2),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Category: ",
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: responsiveText(context: context, fontSize: 18)),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  ValueListenableBuilder<ExpenseCategory>(
                                    valueListenable: selectedCategory,
                                    builder: (context, value, child) {
                                      return Text(
                                        value.name,
                                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: FinTheme.secondaryTextColor, fontSize: responsiveText(context: context, fontSize: 18)),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )),
                              Icon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.chevronRight,
                                size: responsiveText(context: context, fontSize: 16),
                                color: FinTheme.secondaryTextColor,
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ]),
                  )
                ],
              )),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: SizeConstraints.defaultPadding),
                      child: FinButton(
                        label: "Add Tracker",
                        onPressed: () {
                          //Adding the created time and category name to the data model
                          trackerRawModel["createdTime"] = currentDateTime.value;
                          trackerRawModel["category"] = selectedCategory.value.name;
                          if (formKey.currentState != null && formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            formKey.currentState!.save();
                            FinCardDialogue.showDialogue(
                                context: context, widget: FinSalaryDetailsAlertCard(onConfirmed: addEventToWriteStream, onCancel: () => Navigator.pop(context), data: trackerRawModel));
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void addEventToWriteStream(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    /// Creating event for cloud and local
    SalaryDetailsWriteEvent salaryDetailEvent = SalaryDetailsWriteEvent(data: data);
    WriterStream.instance().dispatchEvent(event: salaryDetailEvent);
  }

  void _openCategoryBottomSheetModel({required BuildContext context, required ValueNotifier<ExpenseCategory> selectedCategory}) {
    showModalBottomSheet<int>(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(SizeConstraints.borderRadius * 2), topRight: Radius.circular(SizeConstraints.borderRadius * 2))),
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: responsiveHeight(context: context, offset: 0.7)),
      builder: (context) => Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
        child: FinBottomSheetForCategory(
          currentIndex: ExpenseCategory.values.indexOf(selectedCategory.value),
        ),
      ),
    ).then((value) {
      if (value != null) {
        selectedCategory.value = ExpenseCategory.values[value];
      }
    });
  }

  void _openDateTimeDialogue({required BuildContext context, required ValueNotifier<DateTime> currentDateTime}) {
    showDatePicker(context: context, firstDate: DateTime(1970), initialDate: DateTime.now(), lastDate: DateTime.now()).then((value) {
      if (value != null) {
        DateTime selectedDate = value;
        showTimePicker(context: context, initialTime: TimeOfDay.now()).then((value) {
          if (value != null) {
            currentDateTime.value = DateTime(selectedDate.year, selectedDate.month, selectedDate.day, value.hour, value.minute);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide some codes.

Comment: @Zahra here you go, I had attached code above, thanks in advance

Comment: Cannot run the code. Seems there are some custom implementation that are missing here like ExpenseCategory